# how to split rows into columns separated by pipe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in Pandas

```
data = {'order_id': [123, 221, 234],
        'cust_id': [12, 13, 15],
        'order_total': [2345, 232, 1002],
        'prod_name': ['Chicken wings | Mashroom | Coriander', 'Chicken wings', 'Mashroom | Fish | Garlic']}

order_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   order_id  cust_id  order_total                             prod_name
0       123       12         2345  Chicken wings | Mashroom | Coriander
1       221       13          232                         Chicken wings
2       234       15         1002              Mashroom | Fish | Garlic
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
 order_id    cust_id    order_total   Chicken wings   Mashroom   Coriander    Fish    Garlic
 123         12         2345          1               1          1            0       0      
 221         13         232           1               0          0            0       0
 234         15         1002          0               1          0            1       1
```

I am able to split this into different products, but not able to generate above format.

```
 split_product_df = order_df.prod_name.str.split("|",expand=True).add_prefix('Product_')
```

How can I do this in Pandas.

Comment: @Neil, check the updated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas [str dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) helps with this

@Neil, it seems you have white space in front of the `|`, so try this below, where we search for whitespace followed by `|` and replace it :

```
pd.concat(
    (df.iloc[:, :-1], df.prod_name.str.replace("\s+(?=\|)", "").str.get_dummies()),
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: I am just curious, if there are repeating labels in the string separated by pipe, will this approach work?

Comment: @AnimeshMukherkjee  what do you mean by repeating labels? could you share an example?

Comment: like if it was a|b|c|a (quoting from the str dummies documentatin) should a column have value 1 for the row or 2 ?

Comment: you wil get two rows for column 'a', since it appears twice

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply of pandas from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html on index.
Sharing a similar simpler example, here if your pipe containing string has duplicate labels the following will not work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'order_id': [123, 456],
    'cust_id': [12, 13],
    'order_total': [2345, 6789],
    'prod_name': ["Chicken wings | Mashroom | Coriander", "Mashroom | Fish | Garlic"]
})


def process(row):
    index = row.name # get the index of row
    for word in row['prod_name'].split('|'):
        # for each word separated by | remove spaces and for that index create a column add count as 1
        w = word.lstrip().rstrip()
        df.loc[index, w] = 1


df.apply(process, axis=1) # apply the process on each row
df.drop('prod_name', axis=1, inplace=True) # drop the prod_name column
df = df.fillna(0) # fill nans with zero
```